# how to open multiple pages in single window in pyqt?

Tags: python

I created two windows

First window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from dial import Ui_dial
from chat import Ui_Chat

class Ui_Form(object):

def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(764, 719)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setKerning(False)
    Form.setFont(font)
    Form.setStyleSheet()
 self.call_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.call_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 500, 111, 71))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.call_button.setFont(font)
    self.call_button.setStyleSheet("")
    self.call_button.setText("")
    icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Images/call.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.call_button.setIcon(icon2)
    self.call_button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(58, 58))
    self.call_button.setCheckable(True)
    self.call_button.setAutoExclusive(True)
    self.call_button.setObjectName("call_button")
    self.call_button.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Space))
    self.call_button.clicked.connect(self.dialwindow)
 self.ilabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
    self.ilabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 60, 331, 191))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Sylfaen")
    font.setPointSize(18)
    self.ilabel.setFont(font)
    self.ilabel.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/Images/label_back1.jpg);")
    self.ilabel.setObjectName("ilabel")
 self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
import icons_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":   
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Second Window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import dial_rc

class Ui_dial(object):

def setupUi(self, dial):
    dial.setObjectName("dial")
    dial.resize(739, 712)
    dial.setStyleSheet()
self.dialpage_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(dial)
    self.dialpage_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 120, 301, 511))
    self.dialpage_label.setObjectName("dialpage_label")
    self.callend_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(dial)
    self.callend_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 520, 91, 71))
    self.callend_button.setText("")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Images/end.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.callend_button.setIcon(icon)
    self.callend_button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 45))
    self.callend_button.setObjectName("callend_button")
    self.callend_button.clicked.connect(self.endcall)
def retranslateUi(self, dial):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    dial.setWindowTitle(_translate("dial", "Dialog"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dial = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_dial()
    ui.setupUi(dial)
    dial.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How to show this different windows in single window?when click on button new window is open ,so i want show when i click on the button that second window  open in same screen.so i need expertise on this problem

Answer (score 0):

First modify your python script so that the class inherits from QtWidgets.QMainWindow
by

```
class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.Qdialog):
```

Then write an **init** function so that your class can be instantiated, i.e an object can be created. Once that is done, you can chuck out the QtWidgets.QDialog() object, the one that goes by the name dial in your script, being passed to your setupUI(). Then replace this object being passed with self.

Overall your code will look like this.

```
class Ui_dial(QtWidgets.Qdialog):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()//inheriting from the object.
def setupUi(self, dial):
    self.setObjectName("dial")
    self.resize(739, 712)
    self.setStyleSheet()
    self.dialpage_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(dial)
    self.dialpage_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 120, 301, 511))
    self.dialpage_label.setObjectName("dialpage_label")
    self.callend_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(dial)
    self.callend_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 520, 91, 71))
    self.callend_button.setText("")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Images/end.png"),
def retranslateUi(self):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    self.setWindowTitle(_translate("dial", "Dialog"))
```

Do the same for your other script and then make objects of these classes and call them as,

```
First_window = Ui_Form()
First_window.show()
Second_window = Ui_dial()
Second_window.show()
```

You might need to use resize() to adjust the two windows and to accommodate them according to your needs.